# ExceptionFilter doesn't run .NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, action-filter, custom-action-filter

I have problem with Action Filters. None of my filters run. I am using .NET Core 2.2 and building Web Api. I registered it with     [CustomExceptionFilter] in controller:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
[CustomExceptionFilter]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
                var piano = _repository.GetPianoById(id);
                if (piano == null) throw new Exception(); 
                _repository.Delete(id);
                return Ok();
        }
```

Here is my Exception filter:

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        String message = String.Empty;
        var exceptionType = actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetType();
        if (exceptionType == typeof(Exception))
        {
            message = "Incorrect ID.";
            status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        actionExecutedContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(message, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"),
            StatusCode = status
    };
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is wrong with your example, but this is how I have done it.

First the exception filter:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
```

I then add the filter to the whole controller, not just an action, although that might work too--I have never tried it:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomExceptionFilterAttribute))]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
```

And in Startup.cs, ConfigureServices, add DI support:

```
services.AddScoped<CustomExceptionFilterAttribute>();
```

This [blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Oct/16/Error-Handling-and-ExceptionFilter-Dependency-Injection-for-ASPNET-Core-APIs) goes into more detail.