# How to debug my code to be able to read my api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to consume my web api from a MVC controller but I keep receiving the error message from the client side saying "failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500".

```html
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<Client> AddUpdateClient(Client _client)
        {
            customer = new Client();
            string apiRes = "";

            using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                var refNum = new char[12];
                var random = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < refNum.Length; i++)
                {
                    refNum[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                }
                _client.ClientNo = new string(refNum).ToUpper();

                var oClientNo = _client.ClientNo;

                StringContent cntClient = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_client), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var result = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:35298/api/Client/", cntClient))
                {
                    apiRes = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Client>(apiRes);
                }

                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Firstname", _client.Firstame);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Lastname", _client.Lastname);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("RefNum", oClientNo);
                _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Successfully success");

                return customer;//RedirectToAction("Index", "Document");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check the terminal or 'Debug' output window. A 500 error means an uncaught backend error.

Comment: Hello, the problem is at this level of my code var result = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:35298/api/Client/", cntClient) when I debug, it is supposed to go to the controller defining the method behind but it is not doing that.

Comment: Do you host / own the server you are posting to?

Comment: If you can't debug your controller, you need to setup error handling in your app. Probably need to setup general logging as well, but the default demo web app should have events being logged to the console....  e..g, see `<aspNetCore ... stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=..." ` at https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1487/enabling-asp_net-core-error-logging.aspx

Comment: And see `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` (or method) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0 , and/or consider exception handler attribute `ExceptionFilterAttribute`  ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/60170073/1462295